# Instagram Landscape Resolution: 1200 px Width or 1080 px Width?

Tags: resolution, landscape, instagram

It seems there are different recommendations for Instagram landscape format image resolutions available out there:

- One say, the image should have 1080 px x 608 px (which is 1.91:1).
- Others say, it should have 1200 px x 628 px (which is also 1.91:1)

What is the recommended resolution nowadays?

Comment: Dave, maybe instagram support can be more helpful for your question

Comment: 1080 by 608 is 1.78:1, not 1.91:1. When you say there are different recommendations, can you provide sources? Are they reliable recommendations?

Comment: Tried to ask a similar question here https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/123149/60903 to encompass various sites and create a single source of info but got no joy either.

Comment: @dmkonlinux, such information will be outdated quite fast and the effort to collect it will become meaningless

Answer (score 1):

All images; max width 1080, max height 1350.
https://help.instagram.com/1631821640426723?helpref=faq_content